# Get a users Name from their ID

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012, client-object-model, sharepoint-hosted-app, csom

As part of my Sharepoint hosted App i am using a list which contains a Person or Group. I am getting the ID of the person by using the following.

```
var ApproverID = currentItem.get_fieldValues()["Approver"].get_lookupId();
```

From here i now want to get the persons name or "DisplayText" but can find anything client side that does this in MSDN.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume in your example `Approver` is a [User field type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.aspx). In SharePoint 2013 CSOM [SP.FieldUserValue object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246963.aspx) represents the value of a user field for a list item.

The following code demonstrates how to get `User Name` from User field:

```
//Get user field value
var assignedToVal = item.get_item('AssignedTo');
var userName = assignedToVal.get_lookupValue();   
console.log(userName);


//Get multi user field value
var assignedToVals = item.get_item('AssignedTo');
for(var i = 0; i < assignedToVals.length;i++) {
     var userName = assignedToVals[i].get_lookupValue();   
     console.log(userName);
}
```

Comment: doesn't show how to get it via User ID. Is that even possible?

Comment: @hitdrumhard yes just use get_lookupId() instead

Answer (score 5):

You need to reference following JavaScript file:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" name="SP.UserProfiles.js" runat="server"
    ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />
```

Than you can access the User Profile Properties as follows:

```
var personProperties;

// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

function getUserProperties() {

    // Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
    // var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";
    var targetUser = currentItem.get_fieldValues()["Approver"].get_lookupValue();

    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Get user properties for the target user.
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
    // getMyProperties method.
    personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(personProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {

    // Get a property directly from the PersonProperties object.
    var messageText = " \"DisplayName\" property is "
        + personProperties.get_displayName();

    // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
    messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
        + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
    $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

Reference:

[How to: Retrieve user profile properties by using the JavaScript object model in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx)